# What do companies mean when they say your idea has to be patent or potentially patentable?

Tags: patentability

Does it mean that it simply must be able to become patent, and not have a similar patent already filed?

Comment: There are requirements in general. But for a more thorough answer you should tell us what field of technology you are in. Patent requirements are a little different depending on the tech field - i am a patent attorney

Answer (score 1):

It means the idea has to be new (never published) and inventive (not obvious from the state of the art).

I would expand this further, but there are plenty of websites, articles, books, .. explainign this better than I could. Please look up (above mentioned) requirements for patentability. You could google them or click on the patentability tag and start there.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to DonQuiKong's answer, the desire for patentability is motivated by the fact that a patent provides a period of exclusivity which may be enormously valuable.

If someone is going to invest significant capital developing a product they want to ensure sufficient payback. A patent provides typically 20 years of protection from the application date.